# Propel2 reconnect when MySQL server gone away

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, propel2

I have a long-running job, built using `Propel2`. However, sometimes it crashes with the infamous `mysql server has gone away` error. I'd like to recover from this error by reconnecting to the server, maybe after waiting a few seconds. Does anyone have an idea how to force Propel to reconnect after the connection has been lost? I didn't find any clues how to do this from the [Propel](http://api.propelorm.org/2.0-master/) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) API.

Comment: I am having same issue . I tried to set persistent connection , but don't think this will help.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue when in combination with laravel queue. The queue:work daemon is process, after timeout occurs, it does not reconnect by itself. Tried persistent connection as well, that didn't help.

The way I have solved this now, is a little queue/laravel specific, but might help you get to a solution too.

I now force each job that gets handled by the worker, to disconnect the propel connections by using Queue::before() event.

```
$manager = Propel::getConnectionManager('default');
$manager->closeConnections();
```

New requests done by Propel will then create a new connection (this will happen for each new job that is handled by the worker though)

You could perhaps try/catch your query, see what the error/exception is, and when it's 'mysql server has gone away' trigger a disconnect and retry the query